# Graphics look blurry in SFML

Tags: sfml

I'm working on a 2D game using SFML and many textures (which I'm loading from PNG files, created with Gimp) I use are appearing blurry. They're being drawn without any kind of scaling and transformation, and I have confirmed that smoothing is not enabled for the textures, so I'm not sure what would be causing this or how to fix it.

The image I'm trying to draw is on the left, and what I'm seeing instead is on the right (both are heavily zoomed in). [image: blurry vs. correct]

How can I make SFML draw exactly the contents of the images and not apply this effect?

---

Edit: Here's a minimal example of what I'm doing:

```c
#include <SFML/Window.hpp>
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>

int main(){

    sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(128,128), "Minimal example");

    sf::Texture* tex = new sf::Texture;
    tex->loadFromFile("img/bg/0.png");

    sf::Sprite s;
    s.setTexture(*tex);

    window.draw(s);
    window.display();

    while(window.isOpen()){
        sf::Event event;
        while (window.pollEvent(event)) {
            if (event.type == sf::Event::Closed) {
                window.close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It looks like your image might be ever so slightly misaligned with the pixel grid of the display, leading to interpolation between adjacent texels.

Comment: @DMGregory What would cause that? I've been very careful to only use integer coordinates. Unless it has to do with the position of the window on the screen?

Comment: Show us your code. Right now we may only guess.

Comment: @Mario I added an example of what my code is doing.

Comment: Don't know if this will help, but you're supposed to clear the screen and draw the sprites every frame.

Comment: @EpiglottalAxolotl, The position of the window on the screen might matter, especially with high DPI screens.